# Unable to SSH to Amazon Linux instance from windows 10.I have kept my EC2Tutorial.pem on my desktop. Plz Suggest

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud

I am able to connect to Amazon Ec2 instance but unable to ssh from my windows 10 machine to the Public ip. I am using command :

Attaching supportive screenshots:
1> Path of EC2Tutorial.pem:
2> Command for SSh:

Have followed some of the solutions given by people. chmod 400 EC2Tutorial.pem
also failed with error.

ssh -i EC2Tutorial.pem ec2-user@3.85.176.195

Resulted an error as below:
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-43-19 ~]$ ssh -i EC2Tutorial.pem ec2-user@3.85.176.195
Warning: Identity file EC2Tutorial.pem not accessible: No such file or directory                                                                         .
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).

I am following "Ultimate AWS Certified Developer Associate course on Udemy. and want to ssh the same way as suggested. not getting the same result. plz suggest.enter image description here:
Path to EC2Tutorial.pem file.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feK7u.png)

Comment: It says `No such file or directory`. Can you confirm that the key exists in the correct location and that there are no typos in the file name.

Answer (score 1):

```
CHMOD 400 EC2Tutorial.pem
```

is a typical linux command to change the permission of the public key,so that it is no longer available for other users to access, in Windows I'm not sure if that is the best idea.

From windows it is recommended that you use an SSH Client like Putty(which is free to use) as that would help setup the configuration. You have to first install Puttygen and change the public *.pem file into a *.ppk file(which you can use in Putty to log in to the server.)

Here is a documentation on how to do that.

[AWS Document Link for Using SSH with Putty](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html)